# Vanity Profile url using htaccess with PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have `.htaccess` file, `profile.php`, `index.php` and `test.php`.

Let's say we have user `john`

If I will go to website `http://example.org/john`, then I can see `john` profile.
But If I will go to `index.php` or `test.php`, then pages are with error 404 but shouldn't be. It seems that code from htaccess file is crashing every page.

How I can fix `profile.php` and `.htaccess` file to get:

1. If `http://example.org/john` doesn't exist, then show 404 error on the same page, if exist - show this profile
2. Other pages should display if they exist (like `test.php`)

Code:

**.htaccess**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
DirectorySlash Off


RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9\._\-]+)[^.]$ profile.php?user=$1 [NC]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ /$1.php [NC,END]
```

**profile.php**

```
<?php
if ($_GET['user'] != '') {

    echo 'Showing user profile';

} else {

    echo '404 error';

}
```

Comment: Probably you should change the url structure to be something like /profile/john, then you dont need to check for whether .php exists in the url, and makes more sense perhaps.

Comment: @Andrew I should create folder named `profile` and move `profile.php` inside it? How /profile/john will look like in `profile.php`?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot go from php execution back to apache.

You should swap the RewriteRules, so the file to php is performed first and the profile is done second.

Add L after your rule of no additional rewrite is required.

Look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php to send a proper 404 response. Set 404 as the third argument.